# How to make XMPP working with SIP Messaging? It is possible?

Tags: windows, client, xmpp, sip

I’m using FreePBX verison 15.0.23 for VoIP and openfire for IM. I used the Jitsi for both XMPP & SIP but it stopped update by official. Do we any new alternative method?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe https://sip.cheogram.com/ works for you?